# How to refresh or update frame after value changes in text file using Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, refresh

So basically I am reading a valuefrom a text file which is displayed on the Profile frame using a label. 
def view_value(self):
            self.user = self.controller.user
            self.view_value()

```
        with open(self.user + '.txt', "r") as f:
            value_line = 2
            for i, line in enumerate(f):
                if i == value_line:
                    self.value.set(line)
                    self.value.config(textvariable=line)
```

When I go to a different frame to calculate this value again, it will update the text file with the newly calculated value. However, when I go back to the previous page using the back button - the old value is still there. To get the new value to appear I need to reopen/re-run the program.

Is it possible to have the newly updated value displayed on the page without restarting the application? I have tried calling my view_value method to try and update the value and also tried configuring the label from the other class but wasn't able to get it working.

I also realise there are probably a million things wrong with my code, I am very new to Python so apologies!

Comment: You are using `self.allowance` in both `class Profile` and `class CalculateAllowance`. Therefore `self.allowance` is a instance variable bound to that classes. Make it a instance variable in `controller` and access it with `controller.allowance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the `StringVar` `Profile.allowance` in order to make the display in `Profile` page updated.  The **simple** way is adding the following statement before `self.controller.show_frame(Profile)` in `write_to_file()` of `CalculateAllowance` class:

```
self.controller.frames[Profile].allowance.set(self.user_data[2])
```

Also you need to fix the following issues in your code:

- Remove calling `self.view_allowance()` inside `view_allowance()` in `Profile` class as it will cause infinite recursion problem.
- Remove `self.holiday_allowance_amount.config(textvariable=line)` in `view_allowance()` as it wrongly reassigns `textvariable` to a string.